# Google Search Console API multiple dimensions

Tags: php, api, search, console, dimensions

I am having a small problem adding multiple dimensions to the `API` request for Search Console.

If I add the following to `group by country` it works fine.

```
 $filters->setDimension("country");
 $filters->setOperator("equals");
 $filters->setExpression($country);
 $filter->setFilters($filters);
 $filter->setFilters(array($filters));
 $request->setDimensionFilterGroups(array($filter));
```

But if I add another dimension below for device, it skips the `country` dimension and only runs the query with the device dimension. It's perfectly possible to run both according to this on the search console `API` site:

```
    'filters': [{
        'dimension': 'country',
        'expression': 'ind'
      }, {
        'dimension': 'device',
        'expression': 'MOBILE'
    }]
```

So, any idea how I can use them both on a query?

It's probably simply some `PHP code`, but I can't find any documentation on multiple dimensions or any examples anywhere with `PHP` in mind.

Answer (score 2):

It was simple.

$filters->setDimension("country");

$filters->setOperator("equals");

$filters->setExpression($country);

$filters2->setDimension("device");

$filters2->setOperator("equals");

$filters2->setExpression($device);

$filter->setFilters($filters);

$filter->setFilters(array($filters,$filters2));

$request->setDimensionFilterGroups(array($filter));

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for sharing this, Nick - it really helped!
One tiny thing: you won't need the following:

```
$filter->setFilters($filters);
```

as you're setting filters the right way with the next line of code.

Also, I was stuck on the following line:

```
$request->setDimensionFilterGroups(array($filter));
```

as I was passing the $filter object as it is instead of using an array.
I really found this counter-intuitive: this is the only object setDimensionFilterGroups method needs; I'm still wondering why it needs an array instead.

Cheers,

Sal

Answer (score 0):

Nick's answer did helped me start but currently it isn't complete. To help other devs looking for an answer, hope this would help you:

```
$filter_group = new Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilterGroup;
$groups = array(['device', 'mobile', 'equals'], ['country', 'GBR', 'equals']);
$filters = array();

if($groups) {
  foreach ($groups as $key => $group) {
    $filters[$key] = new Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilter;
    $filters[$key]->setDimension($group[0]);
    $filters[$key]->setExpression($group[1]);
    $filters[$key]->setOperator($group[2]);
  }

  $filter_group->setFilters($filters);
}

$request->setDimensionFilterGroups(array($filter_group));
```

Also take note, currently it won't work if in your filter group you have two or more same dimension but different value for filter or `expression`.

e.g.

```
$groups = array(['device', 'mobile', 'equals'], ['device', 'tablet', 'equals']);
```

It is because `OR` operation is currently not supported for filters.

Check [here](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/searchanalytics/query#dimensionFilterGroups.groupType) and this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310954/search-console-api-impressions-dont-add-up-comparing-totals-to-contains-not/34334258#34334258).